# Cannot install PostgreSQL from EnterpriseDB due to error involving "getlocales.exe"

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin, enterprisedb

I am having trouble installing any of the Windows 64-bit PostgreSQL versions here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

I keep getting the same error:

```
There has been an error.
Unknown error while running C:\Temp\postgresql_installer_1f29627219\getlocales.exe
```

Here is part of the Bitrock Installer error log:

> [18:05:31] Using Service Name: postgresql-x64-9.3
>   Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Temp\postgresql_installer_1f29627219\prerun_checks.vbs"
>   Script exit code: 0
>
> Script output:
>   The scripting host appears to be functional.
>
> Script stderr:
>
> Executing C:\Temp\postgresql_installer_1f29627219\vcredist_x64.exe /passive /norestart
>   Script exit code: 0
>
> Script output:
>
> Script stderr:
>
> Executing C:\Temp\postgresql_installer_1f29627219\getlocales.exe 
>   Script exit code:
>
> Script output:
>
> Script stderr:
>
> Unknown error while running C:\Temp\postgresql_installer_1f29627219\getlocales.exe

For context, I am trying to install this so that I can access to the pg_config file which I need to install psycopg2 using Python. I currently have and use pgAdmin III v1.22 - I'm not sure if already having pgAdmin III is part of why I cannot install the PostgreSQL files from the site above.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @FranciscoPuga have you solved it?

Comment: I moved to another postgresql version and the problem was solved. I review this links at that time, maybe one of them will help you. https://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-11039-installation-fails-when-trying-to-install-C-redistributable-td5813004.html https://postgresrocks.enterprisedb.com/t5/About-Postgres-Rocks/PostgreSQL-installation-issues/td-p/673 https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7517415E78F5E940BA56E54EFFAC7878011E3EFC%40exch1.domforestry.forestry.gov.uk

Answer (score 1):

As this is the top question without any solid answer, I'll leave what worked for me.

Following installation solved it for me ON WINDOWS 10, I was getting exact same error. So postgres is missing the following dependency that it needs for its installation.
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe

Incase if you run into the same error again, try installing PostgreSQL 9.6 and uninstall it, and now proceed with your version. What it should do is get rid(kind of reset them) of the dependencies.